# loading external providers issue with openjdk 1.8.0_312

Tags: java, security, ssl

In my application, I am trying to use BCFIPS provider instead of SunJCE. I have done java.security file modifications

```
securerandom.strongAlgorithms=HMACDRBG128:BCFIPS
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider BCFIPS
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.11=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
keystore.type=BCFKS
keystore.type.compat=true
```

and copied **bc-fips-1.0.1.jar** file to **/jre/lib/ext** folder.

this was working till openjdk 8.0.302 version. But failing with **java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BCFIPS** from openjdk 8.0.312 version. Any idea what change in 8.0.312 might have caused this issue?